# Windows fonts not loading correctly on one machine

Tags: windows, fonts

I've recently installed a font "OB____.tff" on 4 Windows 2008 servers. On 3 laptops it works correctly, but on one laptop I can't use it. I've tried to delete C:/system32/Fntcache.Dat and restart, but that didn't help.

I'm quite new when it comes Fonts on Windows. So sorry if I provided not enough details, I'm not quite sure what to include.